# Connections between loops (algebraic structure) and graphs

Tags: reference-request, graph-theory, latin-square

I would like to know whether there are known constructions which provide a bijection between loops (isomorphism classes) and (possibly directed) graphs. Any reference to a useful paper in this direction will be appreciated.

Searching combinations of words "graphs, loops, representation, bijection" the hits contain too many irrelevant links, so I get staked. Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: The question reposted from http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/979879/connections-between-loops-algebraic-structure-and-graphs

Comment: What happens if you try quasigroups instead of loops for your search?

Comment: @TheMaskedAvenger: the search is useless also in that case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't hard to define a class of graphs whose isomorphism classes correspond to the isomorphism classes of loops.  It is easiest using vertex colours: see B. D. McKay, A. Meynert and W. Myrvold, Small Latin squares, quasigroups and loops, J. Combinatorial Designs, 15 (2007) 98-119.

In [**this corrected version**](http://cs.anu.edu.au/~bdm/papers/ls_final_corr.pdf) the construction is $G_3(L)$ on page 13. You might have to adjust it a little to achieve exactly what you need.

Comment: Thank you very much. This knowledge is very helpful. btw. Is there known any available database of isomorphism classes of loops of order 7? From the LOOPS package of GAP I can get them systematically up to order 6. For higher orders it can generate a loop randomly, but not systematically.

Comment: @Stefan: I'm not aware of such a list, though it would be routine to make them as there are only 23,746. If you can't find a list soon (or someone tells us where one is) let me know and I'll make them.

Comment: I have checked homepages of Andries Brouwer, Patric Ostergard, Ted Spence, Ian Wanless and yours (Did I miss anybody?) but no such data been found.

Comment: They are now on my Latin Squares page: http://cs.anu.edu.au/~bdm/data/latin.html

Comment: I think we have such a construction without using colours. Are you aware of such result without colours? I couldn't find any reference neither in your paper, nor elsewhere.

Comment: @Stefan: All coloured graph isomorphism problems can be converted to uncoloured problems, so just the existence is not news, but it would nice if your construction is substantially different from the previous ones.

Comment: OK, thank you. Our graphs are directed strongly regular graphs.